# TListView scroll event

Tags: delphi, listview, scroll, scrollbar

Does the TListView control have an event that will fire whenever the control is scrolled?

I would prefer not to have to sub-class the TListView control.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Yes, that is it.

Comment: You need to listen for WM_VSCROLL.

Answer (score 7):

This works perfectly, but might violate the constraints of your question.

In the `interface` section of the unit containing the form that use the `TListView` (prior to the `TForm` declaration), add

```
type
  TListView = class(ComCtrls.TListView)
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  end;
```

Then, in the `implementation` section of the same unit, define

```
procedure TListView.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  case Message.Msg of
    WM_HSCROLL, WM_VSCROLL: beep;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: How safe/legal is this trick? Won't there be problems as Delphi expects the control to be a different TListView? (e.g. form designer works with controls which are registered and this one isn't)

Answer (score 3):

You can subclass a window without writing a descendant class, which is useful when you expect the changed behavior to be a one-off requirement. Write a [`TWndMethod`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TWndMethod) function like in [Andreas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478713/tlistview-scroll-event/5478882#5478882), but write it in whatever class you want, such as the form that owns the list view. Assign it to the list-view control's [`WindowProc`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TControl.WindowProc) property. Before you do that, store the property's previous value so you can defer all other messages to it.

```
type
  TNanikForm = class(TForm)
    ListView: TListView;
  private
    FPrevListViewProc: TWndMethod;
    procedure ListViewWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
  public
    procedure Loaded; override;
  end;

procedure TNanikForm.ListViewWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  case Msg.Message of
    wm_VScroll: ;
    else FPrevListViewProc(Msg);
  end;
end;

procedure TNanikForm.Loaded;
begin
  inherited;
  FPrevListViewProc := ListView.WindowProc;
  ListView.WindowProc := ListViewWndProc;
end;
```

Comment: I was ready to post an almost identical answer to this making just the same point. However, I've discovered that just listening to WM_VSCROLL isn't enough. That works for manipulation of the scroll bar, but if you use the mouse wheel or keyboard navigation, then it doesn't fire. I've looked into the LVN_ENDSCROLL notification message which it would seem would help, but I can't get my code to catch once of those.

Comment: In fact the more I look at this the more I despair! Perhaps the OnMessage hack is the least evil after all!

Comment: @David, notification messages are sent to the *parent* of the control. Delphi parents then re-send the notification to the designated child after adding a value — `cm_Base`, I think. The common messages have a `C` prefix on their names. Try catching `cm_Notify` instead of `wm_Notify`.

Comment: It's CN_NOTIFY in fact. I can get those, just not LVN_ENDSCROLL. Anyway, from what I've read, it seems that keyboard navigation raises no notification at all, it's internal to the control.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to trap just vertical scroll event, you can use this. Code is almost the same as Andreas posted ...

```
type
  TListView = class(ComCtrls.TListView)
  protected
    procedure WMVScroll(var Message: TWMVScroll); message WM_VSCROLL;
  end;

procedure TListView.WMVScroll(var Message: TWMVScroll);
begin
  inherited;
  Beep;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The all answer is fine :-), but I don't wont to create new child of class. **Thanks everyone for your help :-)!**

---

*My resolution:* I use component (in Delphi 7) **ApplicationEvents** and I check change of **ScrollBar position** (GetScrollPos(ListView.Handle, SB_VERT)).

Comment: The other solutions are much better. You only need to include the code in the unit with the form that has this component. It's called an interposer. Why are you scared of sub-classing? It's a very normal everyday thing to do. Calling GetScrollPos every time an event appears in your message queue is wasteful.

Comment: @Andreas OnMessage is more likely. Really bad idea.

Comment: @Nanik I share your preference not to sub-class the standard components. When I can find a good solution that meets that desire, I take it. However, this is a poor solution which is far worse than sub-classing. You should be more flexible.

Comment: Can you please explicitly tell us which application event you're handling? Post some code, even. Remember, if this is really the best answer, then you're not just answering this for yourself. You're answering it for all future people who come to this site with a similar question, so make it the best you can.